# Define listing for different languages

Tags: listings

I'm writing a thesis where I need to highlight XML, C# and Python code, here is my definition, but all I get is the same highlight for all three types.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,slovak,12pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ucs}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} Nejde dobre s listings package
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hhline}


\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{perpage} 
\usepackage{footmisc}

% \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\makeatletter\chardef\l@nohyphenation=255 \makeatother
\usepackage[slovak=nohyphenation,czech=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\sloppy



\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 2pt
    \futurelet \reserved
}
\newcolumntype{H}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule width 2pt}}



% Colors
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.35,0.35,0.35}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,0.0}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{0.44, 0.44, 0.0}


\lstset{
  language=XML,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape,
  inputencoding=utf8,
  extendedchars=true,
  literate=%
    {á}{{\'a}}1
    {ä}{{\¨{a}}}1
    {č}{{\v{c}}}1
    {ď}{{\v{d}}}1
    {é}{{\'e}}1
    {ě}{{\v{e}}}1
    {í}{{\'i}}1
    {ň}{{\v{n}}}1
    {ó}{{\'o}}1
    {ô}{{\^{o}}}1
    {ř}{{\v{r}}}1
    {š}{{\v{s}}}1
    {ť}{{\v{t}}}1
    {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {ů}{{\r{u}}}1
    {ý}{{\'y}}1
    {ž}{{\v{z}}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1
    {Č}{{\v{C}}}1
    {Ď}{{\v{D}}}1
    {É}{{\'E}}1
    {Ě}{{\v{E}}}1
    {Í}{{\'I}}1
    {Ň}{{\v{N}}}1
    {Ó}{{\'O}}1
    {Ř}{{\v{R}}}1
    {Š}{{\v{S}}}1
    {Ť}{{\v{T}}}1
    {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {Ů}{{\r{U}}}1
    {Ý}{{\'Y}}1
    {Ž}{{\v{Z}}}1
}

\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[s]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
  keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
  morekeywords={xmlns,version,type}% list your attributes here
}






\newenvironment{indentVariation}[1]%
{\begin{list}{}%
    {\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}}%
     \item[]%
    }
{\end{list}}






% Listings
\lstdefinestyle{color}
    {identifierstyle=\color{green}\bfseries, commentstyle=\color{yellow}\bfseries, stringstyle=\color{blue}, keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries,morecomment=[l]{\#}}

\lstset{breakindent=13pt,breaklines=true,inputencoding=utf8,tabsize=2,showtabs=false,tab=$\to$,style=color,basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\bfseries,frame=lines,frameround=tttt}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\small$\circ$}}$}


\lstset{
  language=Python,
  showstringspaces=false,
  formfeed=\newpage,
  tabsize=4,
  commentstyle=\itshape,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  morekeywords={models, lambda, forms}
}

\lstdefinelanguage{CSharp}
{
sensitive=true,
morekeywords=[1]{
abstract, as, base, break, case,
catch, checked, class, const, continue,
default, delegate, do, else, enum,
event, explicit, extern, false,
finally, fixed, for, foreach, goto, if,
implicit, in, interface, internal, is,
lock, namespace, new, null, operator,
out, override, params, private,
protected, public, readonly, ref,
return, sealed, sizeof, stackalloc,
static, struct, switch, this, throw,
true, try, typeof, unchecked, unsafe,
using, virtual, volatile, while, bool,
byte, char, decimal, double, float,
int, lock, object, sbyte, short, string,
uint, ulong, ushort, void},
morecomment=[l]{//},
morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
morecomment=[l][keywordstyle4]{\#},
morestring=[b]",
morestring=[b]',
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: Could you provide a complete `.tex` file? Then I can paste the whole thing into my editor and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: I would suggest something like `\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{...}\lstnewenvironment{mycode}{\lstset{style=mystyle}}{}`